# If I can Special Summon Blue-Eyes Twin Burst Dragon without Polymerization, why would I ever use Polymerization for it?

Tags: yu-gi-oh

The text of [Blue-Eyes Twin Burst Dragon](http://yugioh.wikia.com/wiki/Blue-Eyes_Twin_Burst_Dragon) reads:

> Must be either Fusion Summoned, or Special Summoned by sending the above monsters you control to the Graveyard (in which case you do not use "Polymerization") and cannot be Special Summoned by other ways.

In both of these cases would the Twin Burst Dragon be starting off in the Extra Deck? If so, if I can Special Summon it just by having the two [Blue-Eyes White Dragon](http://yugioh.wikia.com/wiki/Blue-Eyes_White_Dragon)s and without [Polymerization](http://yugioh.wikia.com/wiki/Polymerization), why *would* I used Polymerization for it? Why waste the spell?

Comment: You are aware that you can also use Blue Eyes Alternative White Dragon right? Part of it's special ability is that it's name becomes Blue Eyes White Dragon while it's face-up on the field. So if you use it's effect to reveal a Blue eyes and the special Blue eyes, you could instantly get it on the field. Blue Eyes Twin Burst Dragon is really not that hard to get on the field.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[Polymerization](http://yugioh.wikia.com/wiki/Polymerization) allows you to use cards in your hand as material, the special summon ability of [Blue Eyes Twin Burst Dragon](http://yugioh.wikia.com/wiki/Blue-Eyes_Twin_Burst_Dragon) specifies sending monsters you control to the graveyard, you only control a monster if it is on your field. With Polymerization you don't need to get the [Blue Eyes White Dragon](http://yugioh.wikia.com/wiki/Blue-Eyes_White_Dragon)s onto the field first.

Polymerization becomes a shortcut to speed up the summon, potentially allowing this summon first turn, preventing the need to spend the turns getting tributes for the blue eyes on the field, or use other cards to special them out and then special summon Twin Burst using it's special summon effect.

Comment: I wish I could accept two answers, you and DarkCygnus are both doing a great job on all these questions. I'm practically flipping a coin on whose I mark as 'accepted'.

Comment: @Aerovistae don't flip coins for that haha. Decide based on what answer works better for you, what has better/more detailed info, etc.

Answer (score 3):

I should warn you that, perhaps, you may be playing your [Blue Eyes Twin Burst Dragon](http://yugioh.wikia.com/wiki/Blue-Eyes_Twin_Burst_Dragon) incorrectly (as per your "just by having...").

Let's break down the effect of that card:

> Must be either Fusion Summoned,

This means that one option to Fusion summon it by using [Polymerization](http://yugioh.wikia.com/wiki/Polymerization), as you correctly pointed out, or...

> or Special Summoned by sending the above monsters you **control** to the Graveyard (in which case you do not use "Polymerization")

instead Special Summon it by sending both [Blue Eyes White Dragon](http://yugioh.wikia.com/wiki/Blue-Eyes_White_Dragon)s to the GY. Do note that you **control** things that are on your part of the *field*. Things on hand are *not* under your control; they are under your *possession*, though, and you also surely are the *owner* of that card. These are other two important in-game terms to remember.

> and cannot be Special Summoned by other ways.

Meaning no [Call of the Haunted](http://yugioh.wikia.com/wiki/Call_of_the_Haunted), or back from Banish, nor anything similar. If it's dead, its dead (time for [Dragon Mirror](http://yugioh.wikia.com/wiki/Dragon%27s_Mirror) maybe?).

---

Under these considerations we can see that if you want to use the Special Summon you must have two Blue-Eyes White Dragon on the field (or at least two cards with that name ;) if you copycat one). This is more restricted as being able to do this from the hand (quite OP to do don't you think?).

Or you can well Fusion summon to be able to use them as materials from your hand or the field (more accessible, but requires Polymerization or similar)

As we can see, either Polymerization or having two Blue Eyes on the field is a "reasonable" requirement to summon such powerful card. Thus, both summon ways balance each other (so it does not become broken).

Comment: I was actually playing it correctly, I just kind of forgot that you can also polymerize fusion materials from your hand. Beginner mistake. Should have known this.

Comment: @Aerovistae good to hear that, sorry if I assumed. And yes, you can Poly with material from your hand, which gives you advantage as you won't have to summon 2 blue-eyes

Comment: (I decided to mark Andrew's answer as accepted this time just because it's a quicker read so it might be a faster solution for future readers....both your answers are great.)

Comment: @Aerovistae it's Ok. Next time I'll try to be more brief, however I *do* like to give detailed answers as I find them more valuable.

Comment: You don't need to be more brief, really! Your answers are great.

Comment: Plus, there are card effects that only trigger when a monster is Fusion Summoned, rather than just Special Summoned (e.g. [Magical Meltdown](http://yugioh.wikia.com/wiki/Magical_Meltdown) - it stops Polymerization being negated, and stops your opponent using a spell, trap or monster effect in response to the Fusion Summon)

Answer (score -3):

If you fusion summoned Blue-eyes twin burst dragon, you will be able to used fusion substitued, and also be able to avoid having its fusion summoned negated, while if you used its contact method they most be on the field to be considered control, and you can used face-down blue-eyes white dragon for its contact fusion, but you cannot used a face-down blue-eyes alternative dragon(if he his face-down because of book of moon)and if summoned that way your opponent can negated the summoned with solemn warning, or solemn strike, and solemn judgment. A lot of people that are new to yugioh because the contact fusion description as (you do not used polymerization) they think if you don't used specifically polymerization for the fusion, and you used other fusion card like dragon mirror, they think your doing the contact fusion, and my opponent argued in DB that he could negated the summoned when I fusion summoned blue-eyes twin burst with dragon mirror, But fang of critias, his a spell card that activated that does a contact fusion, but because your useing a spell card to make the contact happen, your opponent cannot negated the summoned.